# Is it possible to change the dependencies of a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, downgrade

I would like to change the dependencies of the package `slack-desktop`. My case is complex, but I will try to explain it why i wanna do this. I want to downgrade slack-desktop using this command `sudo apt install slack-desktop=3.1.1`, but I am getting this error:

> slack-desktop : Depends on: libcurl3 it cannot be installed

It is translated from Bulgarian as my Ubuntu is in Bulgarian. I want to downgraded version of slack because the latest version of slack 3.3.3 it is not working with Ubuntu 18.10. Also I am getting this error because I already have installed libcurl4 on my system and i dont want to downgrade it as many of my packages depends on it as well, so i dont want to have slack and loose a other packages, so my question is can i change the dependencies of a package when installing it with apt?

Side node: I already know that i can download the deb package and manipulate it and change libcurl3 to libcurl4 rebuild the deb file and installed it, but when i run `apt update/upgrade` it is always upgrading slack-desktop as well **even** i have told him to **hold** the package and dpkg hold as well.

Someone can suggest something

Output of `apt-cache policy slack-desktop libcurl3 libcurl4`:

```
slack-desktop:
  Installed: 3.3.3
  Candidate: 3.3.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.3 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.0-beta25a7a50e 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.1.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.1.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.5 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.9.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.6.3 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.6.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.6.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.5.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.5.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.4 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.3 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.6 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.5 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.4 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.3 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.0 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.6 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.5 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.4 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.3 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.2 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.1 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libcurl4:
  Installed: 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.61.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: `libcurl3` and `libcurl4` are different packages (as opposed to different versions of the same package), so you can install both.

Comment: I dont think so as when i try to install `libcurl3` I get error that i cant install this package because the following packages are substituting it `libcurl4:i386 libcurl4
`

Comment: Please provide the ouptut of `LC_ALL=C apt-cache policy slack-desktop libcurl3 libcurl4`.

Comment: here it is https://pastebin.com/M6jFjR0k

Comment: The repository you have is for Debian Jessie; are you sure it is appropriate for Ubuntu? Dependencies problem like that are very often caused by incorrect repositories.

Comment: i got it. i have the Debian Jessie version because i used repo of this version, but now i deleted and i wanted to install the 3.1.1 version using a deb file i got from internet, but when i try to do this i get an error `the package libcurl3 is not installed`